# IFrame в Chrome выдает 302 код

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, apache2

Пишу небольшой скрипт.

В страницу js-код внедряет IFrame.

Прикол: Mozilla Firefox все загружает, все отлично. Google Chrome IFrame не загружает (Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.)

Заголовки:

```
Request URL:https://nextcloud.ru/index.php/login
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:92.126.152.50:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Language:ru
Content-Length:0
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-eXdSWWVVWlZtVkJ5UjUxOE5JYVBic2pKR2pUVUEzaHM4Z1krVE4vb2NiOD06dlZ3MUF5NEN3RHNVTXJZNVZiN2dLZjJJS21DdVN4NHVtVkJRQlk2WUU4dz0='; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; img-src * data: blob:; font-src 'self' data:; media-src *; connect-src *
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 15 Sep 2017 05:31:53 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=80
Location:/index.php/login
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.27 (FreeBSD) PHP/7.1.9 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.5 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-freebsd
Set-Cookie:__Host-nc_sameSiteCookielax=true; path=/; httponly;secure; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2100 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=lax
Set-Cookie:__Host-nc_sameSiteCookiestrict=true; path=/; httponly;secure; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2100 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=strict
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Download-Options:noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies:none
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.9
X-Robots-Tag:none
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
**Request Headers**
view source:
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:oc_sessionPassphrase=9oSU02HnFPDxv3niKHNSkvOpPO2FKGsCfWXvmey08pzVuz9kmPgNmcSlZUDnp9RtTVIhQ6qyakbLFs%2BM795gUjC38B3EHiutZhICMYAos%2BigRmehEpvhuPXCP1Hy5cyV; ocszcxtn03dt=bs50k57gmanvamqgi1mneoho76; _ga=GA1.2.45064223.1505119790; _gid=GA1.2.1676476445.1505451812
Host:nextcloud.ru
Referer:https://m.mysite.ru/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36`
```

И *оборванный* запрос на этот же сайт

```
Request URL:https://nextcloud.ru/index.php/login
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Referer:https://m.mysite.ru/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

В чем беда и как его исправить?

Comment: Ни браузер, ни гугль не знают такого сайта `nextcloud.ru` :)

Comment: Самое смешное, что когда из того же хрома перехожу на страницу (новая вкладка) https://nextcloud.ru/index.php/login то все нормально открывается